# Add rows to pandas dataframe using column of dictionaries

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this:

```
matrix = [(222, {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c':2, 'd':1}),
         (333, {'a': 1, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':1})]

df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['ordernum', 'dict_of item_counts'])
```

```
   ordernum               dict_of item_counts
0       222  {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}
1       333  {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}
```

and I would like to create a dataframe in which each `ordernum` is repeated for each dictionary key in `dict_of_item_counts` that is not 0. I would also like to create a `key` column that shows the corresponding dictionary key for this row as well as a `value` column that contains the dictionary values. Finally, I would also an `ordernum_index` that counts the different rows in the dataframe for each `ordernum`.

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
ordernum      ordernum_index      key     value

222           1                   a       1
222           2                   b       3 
222           3                   c       2
222           4                   d       1
333           1                   a       1
333           2                   d       1
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try to structure your data, Can be done easily like below:

```
>>> matrix
[(222, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}), (333, {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1})]
>>> data = [[item[0]]+[i+1]+list(value) for item in matrix for i,value in enumerate(item[1].items()) if value[-1]!=0]
>>> data
[[222, 1, 'a', 1], [222, 2, 'b', 3], [222, 3, 'c', 2], [222, 4, 'd', 1], [333, 1, 'a', 1], [333, 4, 'd', 1]]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ordernum', 'ordernum_index', 'key', 'value'])
   ordernum  ordernum_index key  value
0       222               1   a      1
1       222               2   b      3
2       222               3   c      2
3       222               4   d      1
4       333               1   a      1
5       333               4   d      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand the dictionary by using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate that to your other column (ordernum). See below for your in-between result of `df2`.
Now to turn every column into a row, use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), then use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to drop all the 0-rows and finally [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the index (after ordering) and add 1 to start counting from 1, not 0.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df[['ordernum']], df['dict_of item_counts'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
(df2.melt(id_vars='ordernum', var_name='key')
.query('value != 0')
.sort_values(['ordernum', 'key'])
.assign(ordernum_index = lambda df: df.groupby('ordernum').cumcount().add(1)))
#   ordernum key  value  ordernum_index
#0       222   a      1               1
#2       222   b      3               2
#4       222   c      2               3
#6       222   d      1               4
#1       333   a      1               1
#7       333   d      1               2
```

Now df2 looks like:

```
#   ordernum  a  b  c  d
#0       222  1  3  2  1
#1       333  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by unpacking your dictionarys while accesing them with [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and creating a tuple out of the `ordernum, key, value`.

Finally to create your `ordernum_index` we groupby on `ordernum` and do a [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
data = [(r['ordernum'], k, v) for _, r in df.iterrows() for k, v in r['dict_of item_counts'].items() ]

new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ordernum', 'key', 'value']).sort_values('ordernum').reset_index(drop=True)

new['ordernum_index'] = new[new['value'].ne(0)].groupby('ordernum').cumcount().add(1)
new.dropna(inplace=True)
```

---

```
   ordernum key  value  ordernum_index
0       222   a      1             1.0
1       222   b      3             2.0
2       222   c      2             3.0
3       222   d      1             4.0
4       333   a      1             1.0
7       333   d      1             2.0
```

Comment: The key which has 0 value must be excluded as per OP.

Answer (score 0):

Construct dataframe `df1` using `df['dict_of item_counts'].tolist()` for values and `df.ordernum` for index. `replace` 0 with `np.nan` and `stack` with dropna=True to ignore 0 values. `reset_index` to get all columns.

Next, create column `ordernum_index` by using `groupby` and `cumcount`.

Finally, change column names to appropriate names.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['dict_of item_counts'].tolist(), index=df.ordernum).replace(0, np.nan).stack(dropna=True).reset_index(name='value')
df1['ordernum_index'] = df1.groupby('ordernum')['value'].cumcount() + 1
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'level_1': 'key'})

Out[732]:
   ordernum key  value  ordernum_index
0       222   a    1.0               1
1       222   b    3.0               2
2       222   c    2.0               3
3       222   d    1.0               4
4       333   a    1.0               1
5       333   d    1.0               2
```